# How do I write a generic Swift extension to deep merge two dictionaries?

Tags: swift, dictionary, generics, recursion

I'm trying to write a function to deep merge two dictionaries. By this I mean that when the values for a key in both dictionaries are being merged and those values are both dictionaries, they will be merged instead of one being replaced by the other.

Here's what I have:

```
extension Dictionary {
    public func deepMerged(with other: [Key: Value]) -> [Key: Value] {
        var result: [Key: Value] = self
        for (key, value) in other {
            if let value = value as? [Key: Value], let existing = result[key] as? [Key: Value] {
                result[key] = existing.deepMerged(with: value)
            } else {
                result[key] = value
            }
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

But unfortunately it doesn't compile. I get the error

> Cannot convert value of type '[Key : Value]' to expected argument type [_ : _]' on the use of value in the recursive call to `deepMerged(with:).

I'm able to work around this by scoping the extension:

```
extension Dictionary where Key == String, Value == Any {
    ...
}
```

This works for my particular use case at this time, but I don't understand why the more generic code doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the error is on the assignment to `result[key]`, not on the function call itself:

```
let merged: [Key:Value] = existing.deepMerged(with: value)  //works fine
result[key] = merged                                        //error
```

The compiler knows that:

- `result` is a `[Key: Value]`
- `other` is a `[Key: Value]`
- `key` is a `Key`
- `value` is a `Value`
- `merged` is a `[Key:Value]`
- `result` has a `subscript(key: Key) -> Value? { get set }` (i.e. a writable subscript of type `Value?` which accepts a `Key`)

But it does *not* know that `[Key:Value]` is a `Value`, so it does not know that `merged` can be passed to the subscript of `result`.  Since `value` is a `Value` and `value` is also `[Key: Value]`, we know that `[Key: Value]` must be a `Value`, but the compiler does not know that.

A solution is to cast `merged` to a `Value`:

```
extension Dictionary {
    public func deepMerged(with other: [Key: Value]) -> [Key: Value]
    {
        var result: [Key: Value] = self
        for (key, value) in other {
            if let value = value as? [Key: Value],
                let existing = result[key] as? [Key: Value],
                let merged = existing.deepMerged(with: value) as? Value
            {
                result[key] = merged
            } else {
                result[key] = value
            }
        }
        return result
    }
}
```